# Deploying a cluster (i.e. MongoDb / ElasticSearch) with Docker and linking to Java Application

Tags: docker

I need to deploy a Java microservice which interacts with an high-available back-end, such as ElasticSearch  or Mongodb.

- What is the idiomatic way to deploy a cluster of an high-available backend such as ElasticSearch or MongoDb and then pass the information to a dockerized microservice?
- Port and container links seems to tie the application to be always deployed with docker, is that a significant drawback?
- Is there an idiomatic way to retrieve the ip of the machines and pass them to the container running the microservice?

Answer (score 1):

Since docker 1.9, the new idiomatic way would be to run a discovery service like **[Consul](https://www.consul.io/)**, in order to record any container and advertise it to other containers. No more links.

See an example in "[Atlassian Orchestration with Docker: multi-host support for the win!](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/12/atlassian-docker-orchestration/)".
You isolate your different services on a 3-node **[Swarm cluster](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/)**:

[image: https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/12/atlassian-docker-orchestration/arch.png]

The idea behind using swarm and different nodes is that you can allocate different constraints per node (in term of memory) in order to assign the right service to the right node.

Comment: are there drawbacks in coupling the deployment of the app with Docker or one can safely assume that it will anyways deploy production environments which are dockerized too?

Comment: The idea is to be able to specify (declare in a text file) that deployment with docker-compose. That same description should work anywhere where docker 1.9 is installed.

Comment: is it safe to assume that my prod infrastructure will always be dockerized?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 amways? no. But if it is, then this kind of architecture is recommended.